# Постановка запятой в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

"Из-за твоего иррационального мышления, в диалоге отсутствует конструктивность" - нужна ли здесь поставленная мной запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из-за твоего иррационального мышления в диалоге отсутствует конструктивность.
Отсутствует почему? Из-за чего? - обстоятельство, выраженное словосочетанием, которое не является ни деепричастным оборотом, ни оборотом с предлогами несмотря, согласно, вопреки. **Оснований для постановки запятой нет.**

Answer (score 0):

Из-за твоего иррационального мышления в диалоге отсутствует конструктивность.

**В данном предложении запятая не нужна,** обстоятельственный оборот со значением причины является детерминантом, то есть относится ко всему предложению. Обособить его можно, повысив его статус (сделав аналогом придаточного предложения), но для этого нужно распространить оборот, предложение или и то и другое, например:

**Вследствие твоего иррационального мышления,  в нашем диалоге практически всегда отсутствует конструктивность.**